# how do I insert strings with newlines from html textarea into a html table?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, datatables

I have a HTML textarea with a string split across multiple lines. for example

```
cat
dog
horse
```

What I'm then trying to do is insert these strings into a html table. the HTML table ( I'm using jquery.datatables) seems to ignore the newlines. So what I'm

```
<textarea id='txttest' name="texttest" ></textarea>
```

I've tried replacing the text like so but both of these do not work.

```
var res = $("textarea#txttest").val().replace(/\/n/,"<br>");
```

or

```
var res = $("textarea#txttest").val().replace(/&#10/,"<br>");
```

I then insert the result into my datatable

```
$('table#table_flows').dataTable().fnAddData( [
  res ] );
```

but the newlines are not being replaced by < br >

How do I do this?

thank you.

Comment: did you try `<br/>` , in iOS it causes problem with out closing tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra slash in your `.replace` and you need to add a `g` to make it a global replace rather than just the first occurence.

Try

```
var res = $("textarea#txttest").val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yE9tX/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: split into an array using NewLine as separator, then rejoin the string array with `<br />`

```
var res = $("textarea#txttest").val().split("\n").join('<br />');

$('table#table_flows').dataTable().fnAddData( [  res ] );
```

[Check the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/sSJv5/)

Comment: Definitely simplifies my answer. I forget simple things like `join` exists... -.- lol

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try any example using `replace()`, like you were just doing. Instead, I put together an example using `split()` that splits the value at the `\n` character.

http://jsfiddle.net/TY22g/

```
var cell = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
textarea.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var array = textarea.value.split("\n");
    var i = 0, length = array.length;
    for (i; i < length; i++) {
        cell.innerHTML += array[i] + "<br/>";
    }
});
```